# numpy.ones results in red, green, blue, and black bars on image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((512, 256, 3)).astype(int)*255
image = Image.fromarray(a, "RGB")
image.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

I would expect this to result in a white image of size 512x256.
Instead, I get this:

[image: Columns of color image]

For some reason, this image is a series of bars rather than a solid color.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the format of the numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `astype(int)` use `astype(np.uint8)` or even better

```
a = np.full((512, 256, 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
```

The stripes you are seeing are the result of int values reinterpreted as sequences of `uint8`s.

Comment: Oh!! That last sentence was extremely helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: Finally! I just couldn't track down my error and turns out it was something weird like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Image.new` instead.

```
image = Image.new('RGB', (512, 256), color=(255, 255, 255))
image.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: That worked! But now how would I manage to change the values in this image?

Comment: @NoahWillCrow Modify the `color` tuple to change the colour as needed.

Comment: Sorry, no, I mean, how can I change the values on a per-pixel basis to say draw a triangle? Like, what data format do I need in order to use Image.putdata?

Comment: @NoahWillCrow Ah, not too familiar with PIL to answer that, sorry!